# Haskell readCreateProcessWithExitCode

Tags: haskell

How do you debug failures of readCreateProcessWithExitCode? I have a specific line of code:

```hs
readProcessWithExitCode "./tlsfSynt.sh" ltlCommandArgs []
```

That claims to fail:

```
tslsynth: ./tlsfSynt.sh: readCreateProcessWithExitCode: posix_spawnp: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

And yet the file does exist in the cwd and I can verify that the program itself can see it, by running this just above the previous command:

```hs
currentFiles <- getDirectoryContents "."
print currentFiles
```

and getting the output:

```
[".","..",...several files...,"tlsfSynt.sh",...several more files...]
```

Comment: Do you have executable permission to that file?

Comment: I do. However, I figured out the answer. It was actually the shebang line inside the file. It's a bit odd that this is indistinguishable from the file not existing.

Comment: It is not exactly odd. The shebang line is meant to specify the interpreter. If it specifies something that does not exist, that's the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

The way to debug it is to check multiple possibilities. This doesn't mean the file doesn't exist.

1. The file could not exist
2. The file could not have correct permissions
3. There could be a ENOENT error from inside the execution of the file

Without more information, you can't tell.